login into QSAN XEVO API , curl, terminal
I am trying to login into QSAN XEVO API to get some statistics from there
I created a user from XEVO web interface, who can only read. Than for a test i try to login with the new account into XEVO web. I manage to log in without problems. I even try to open https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rest/ while i am logged into the new read only account and i am seeing some data from the API.
than i try to use curl from the terminal
curl -k -c ./qsancookie.txt -X POST https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/auth/get -d '{"user":"newuser", "password":"userpassword", "offlineAccess":"true"}'

the api responded with:
{"error":{"message":"Incorrect password or account","code":1}}  

i am 10000% shure that my user and password are correct!
I found another method and i try with:
   curl -k -c ./qsancookies.txt -X POST https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rest/login/account/newuser/password/userpassword

but the response was:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>411 - Length Required</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>411 - Length Required</h1>
 </body>
</html>

what i am doing wrong?
